# disable form field saving in browser, autocomplete

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to disable autocomplete feature in browser and put  autocomplete="off" attribute on Input. I have tried to use code below but it do not put autocomplete="off" on generated Input html tag. What is the correct way to do this?

```
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { autocomplete = "off" })
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`@Html.EditorFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee834942.aspx) doesn't take an `object htmlAttributes` as a second argument (or any argument for that matter).

Try using [`@Html.TextBoxFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor.aspx) instead:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { autocomplete = "off" })
```

Comment: you beat me to it this is indeed the answer

Answer (score 3):

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" autocomplete="off" 
  action="http://www.example.com/form.cgi">
```

Comment: like that you mentioned autocomplete for the whole form, but you need to show the Razor way of doing this since the question was posted with Razor:  @using(Html.BeginForm("myaction","mycontroller",FormMethod.Post, new { autocomplete = "off" })) { ... }